# Intelligent Y Axis Scaling BarPlot R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I want to plot some data with barplot. Rather, I want to make a bar graph and barplot seemed the logical choice. I am plotting just fine but I was wondering if there is a way to intelligently scale the y axis to round up from the highest count.

For example I set the yaxis in this case to be 30, because I knew that Strand.22 had 27 counts in it: `barplot(unlist(d), ylim=c(0,30), xlab="Forward Reverse", ylab="Counts")`

[image: Graph]

In the future, I want this script to run on its own, so it would be optimal for the the Y-axis to choose it's own ylim. Short of pulling the information out of my 'd' variable I can't think of a good way to do this. Is there an easy way to do this with barplot? Would some other plotter work better? I have seen things about ggplots but it seemed super complex and I wasn't sure that it would do anything better.

EDIT: If I do not choose a ylim it picks automatically and this is what it decided was best.
[image: Chart2]

I disagree with it's choice.

Comment: Don't specify `ylim`?

Comment: @Thomas If I don't specify ylim it automatically picked to range from 0 to 25

Comment: Then set it as something like `ylim=c(0,1.1*max(unlist(d)))`.

Comment: Thank you R wizard. I absolutely would never have thought of that (as I don't understand it). Can you reproduce this as an answer with an explanation? I want to be able to accept this as an answer.

Comment: @Thomas that was a very creative solution !!! Brilliant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify `ylim`, R will come up with something based on the data. (Sounds like you don't like it's choice, which is fair.)

If you specify something based on the data like:

```
barplot(unlist(d), ylim=c(0,1.1*max(unlist(d)))
```

R will draw you a plot that reflects the maximum value of data. That example just takes the maximum of your values and multiplies that by 1.1 (this could be any number) to give it a little extra height. R does something similar to this when you make a scatterplot but it handles barplots slightly differently.